# Object variable of a class as a tuple

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, object, initialization

I am trying to define an **object variable of a class so that it would be a tuple** as seen below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = ? # tuple

    def generate_results(self, a):
        # tuple to hold the 3 result integers
        self.results = (self.calculate_first_result(a),  
                        self.calculate_second_result(a),
                        self.calculate_third_result(a))
```

(where the `calculate_first_result`, `calculate_second_result` and `calculate_third_result` are static methods of `MyClass` which perform some calculations and return an `int`)

I do not understand how the `self.results` in `__init__` should be defined in order for it to hold the **tuple with the 3 integers** as it is calculated in `generate_results` method.

I am new with the class and object variable concepts in Python so any shortcomings in my design and approach will be appreciated.

Comment: Pick the three values for the tuple, then just assign it.  Example: `self.results = (0, 0, 0)` will set it to three zeros.

Comment: You can type: `self.results = ()` and what you did in `generate_results()` will remain valid.

Comment: @TomKarzes But is it not a tuple immutable, so if I set it to `(0, 0, 0)` then I will not be allowed to put inside it the new calculated values?

Comment: You don't need to do it the `__init__` method. Instance variables can be created in any method, so you don't need an `__init__`  in this case.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Could you further explain how this `self.results=()` solves my situation? Perhaps with an example?

Comment: `self.results = ()` solves your problem, but it isn't necessary. Are you coming from Java? Python is different. You can have `self.results = ()`, or assign it anything, and your assignment statement in your generate_results method will assign a new tuple. Python is a dynamic programming language.

Comment: `self.results=()` does indeed work. In the interest of gaining some understanding, could someone explain what it does, perhaps as an answer which I can then accept? (bare in mind that I would certainly prefer an efficient and pythonic answer)

Comment: That way you initialize an empty tuple and later insert whatever values you want.

Comment: Yes, a tuple is immutable.  But that's what you said you wanted.  I'm not sure what your question is.  If you want to use a tuple for this, and you want to change it, then you have to use a new tuple.

Comment: What's the point of using an empty tuple?  It's just as immutable as any other tuple.  Why not just use `None` to initialize it?  For that matter, I really don't see the point of using a tuple for any of this.  Why not just use three distinct instance variables to hold the values?

Comment: @TomKarzes I see what you mean about the use of tuples to hold the results. The only reason that I opted to use tuples is the fact that the value results are always used later (for further calculations etc.) as a group, hence I chose a tuple to hold them. I may change it to distinct instance variables as you suggest and later on group in a tuple. Not sure which of the two is best. Care to offer your advice on this?

Comment: Using individual named variables is always better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally code this:

```
def __init__(self):
        self.results = ()
```

If I judge just from your code, I may say it is not important because inside `generate_results()` you overrided `self.results`.

It can be useful to initialize the empty tuple only **if you need to keep a trace of it** for further needs in your program, otherwise not.

The following code summerizes what I said:

```
class Begueradj:
   def __init__(self):       
       self.results = ()       

   def generate_results(self):
       self.results = (1,2,3) 
       print ' inside generate_results():    '+str(self.results)

   def display(self):
       print ' inside display():    '+str(self.results)


# Main program starts here   
if __name__ =='__main__':

   b = Begueradj()
   b.display() # This line will not work if you do not run self.results = () inside __init__()
   b.generate_results()
   b.display()
```

If you do not need to keep a track of self.results, meaning in our code sample that you do not need to call `display()` just before `generate_results()` method, then this will lead us to what **@juanpa.arrivillaga** commented you: I mean, it will become useless to initialize the empty tuple. The code below reflects this situation:

```
class Begueradj:
   def __init__(self): 
       # Do not do anything
       # We do not need to keep a track of self.results      
       pass       

   def generate_results(self):
       self.results = (1,2,3) 
       print ' inside generate_results():    '+str(self.results)

   def display(self):
       print ' inside display():    '+str(self.results)


# Main program starts here   
if __name__ =='__main__':

   b = Begueradj()
   # b.display() you can no longer call display() here as we did not initialize self.results inside __init__
   b.generate_results()
   b.display()
```